# How to launch a special activity when I exit and run application again?

Tags: android

In my application I have "Principal" activity, so, when I exit application from any other activity and run it again the last activity is launched and not my Principal activity.
So how to launch "Principal" activity every time I exit and run app from any other activity?

what I have now : A is my principal activity, B and C other activity :
A => B => C => exit
when I exit app and run it again C is launched and not A.

Comment: read about `Activity` life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave your principal activity and move to any other activity, you can set this flag
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` to the intent that you use to start the new activity.
This clears any activities which are started after the principal activity in case the user exits the application (mostly using home button).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET

An example of this is:

When launching any activity from your principal activity you can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondaryActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(i);
```

When launching your principal activity you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` so that your principal activity will be on top of the stack of its task.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

When launching your principal activity you can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrincipalActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
startActivity(i);
```

This way you don't have to worry if you exited the application from any other activity than the principal activity.

Please tell me if you have any problem. In case your principal activity is the entry point to your application, I believe you don't have to use the second flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`. However I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks :) it works perfectly , I used FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET